# How to dual boot Linux Mint 18.1 along with windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint 18.1, the latest stable release, on top of Windows 7. The installation went well. However, windows 7 is not listed in the boot loader at all even though I have access its files and partition and I am not too familiar with editing grub or using grub. When I boot my machine, I only get Linux Mint to choose from the boot loader and its advanced option. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Linux Mint 18.1 installation, I stepped through the installation process and when I got to the Disk Management part I used **Guided** option for it to partition the hardrive automatically. For some reason, this option didn't work as it should. The second time I reinstalled Linux Mint 18.1, I decided to partition the hardrive **manually**. Simply, I created a space for root as a primary and swap. Then, after stepping through rest of the installation process it did its thing. Only after doing this, did I see Windows 7 listed in the boot loader along with Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Without an understanding of grub you can use Boot-Repair for automatic grub repair or creation.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You will find the instructions on that page, you should follow option 2 instructions to install as described enter the following 1 line at a time to terminal.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

You can then run the boot-repair program from search or menu. You should be able to just press next for default settings but it always pays to check setting you understand. It always works for me with Mint 17, 18, win 7 and 8.1.

Comment: This was going to be my last option, but I got it to work. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:
1. To boot manually via commands. (That's simple but annoying)
2. To repair GRUB via solution that explained previously.
3. To modify GRUB configuration file.
Solution 1:
Every time your PC boots, press c in GRUB to go to command line.Type the following commands at the GRUB prompt:

```
set root=hd0, msdos1
chainloader +1
boot
```

Solution 2:
Explained previously :https://superuser.com/a/1219340/740779
Solution 3:
Open /boot/grub/grub.cfg with a text editor.
Find this text in the file:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Or something like that, and Paste the following lines after that:

```
menuentry 'Windows' --class windows --class os 
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-889462D09462BFF4' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    chainloader +1
}
```

Hope this work fine for you!